HTML & CSS - VS Code - Live Server Extension issue
I have an issue with the Live Server extension in VS code. I'm learning html & css and I installed the extension when I was working on a file website.html in a folder named Lesson 1. It worked well. The I went on the Lesson 4 folder and tried to open with live server a file named buttons.html, and I got this in chrome :this is what was opened.
What should I do?
I tried to copy the buttons.html file in the Lesson 1 folder and it worked well. Then I tried to change some settings in the extension but I didn't know pretty much what I was doing and it was changing nothing so I got back to default settings. I closed and re-opened VS Code between each test and it didn't help.

Before you start making changes, try to open buttons.html from the default "Web App" configuration. If that doesn't work, look through the file path to make sure you're looking in the right place.

If you had made files in different folder then go to that folder of lesson 4 and use cmd and code. to launch vs code for that folder and then use live server I think the issue you are encountering you might be through directory path
